# How can I choose specific parts of a string?

Tags: r, sna

I need to select Twitter handle names from retweets and create a list of usernames. I wonder how I can select text within a string that start with "@". Here's an example for a retweet.

> @MyBrianLeyh @IngrahamAngle @TombStoneBub @MeticulousPaul @kjross1970 @RealTT2020 @busylizzie48 @LaylaAlisha11…

Thanks!

I've tried the MID function on Excel to select user names. However, I have to specify the length of the (part of the) string. User names have different lengths. So the results are not accurate.

Comment: See `help("regex")` and `help("gsub")`

Comment: Do you want solution in R or Excel?

Comment: `sub("^@", "", c("@MyBrianLeyh","@IngrahamAngle","@TombStoneBub"))` ?

Comment: @RonakShah (1) probably want `gsub` (2) doesn't help if there's anything other than usernames in one of the elements of the character vector

Comment: I tried gsub, and as @duckmayr said, it didn't identify the handles correctly. I am curious to learn how to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I use a string with some Twitter handles and random text as an example. I use `strapplyc` to pull out all text between a `@` and  a space `\\`.

```r
# Test string
test <- "@MyBrianLeyh @IngrahamAngle @TombStoneBub @MeticulousPaul @kjross1970 @RealTT2020 This is part of a tweet @busylizzie48 @LaylaAlisha11 This is another part"

# Load library
library(gsubfn)
#> Loading required package: proto

# Extract all handles between @ and a space
strapplyc(test, "@(.*?)\\ ", simplify = c)
#> [1] "MyBrianLeyh"    "IngrahamAngle"  "TombStoneBub"   "MeticulousPaul"
#> [5] "kjross1970"     "RealTT2020"     "busylizzie48"   "LaylaAlisha11"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: I tried this with a csv file that has a list of retweets. It returns the list of usernames in the  each cell. However, the list does not map the handles back to each tweet. Is there any command to list each handle mentioned in each tweet in separate columns in the same row?

Comment: @ChamilRathnayake It's hard to say without a reproducible example. Can you edit your question to include the data structure (or a subset of the data structure) you're working with? For example, using `dput`.

Comment: This is what I tried. I had retweets in a csv file.#=========library(gsubfn)
handles <- strapplyc(rts, "@(.*?)\\ ", simplify = c)
write.csv(handles, "hanldes_2.csv")#=========